# iOS: Localized UILabel text is missaligned

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, localization, uilabel

I'm updating an app to include localization for English (base) and Spanish.  On my login screen in Storyboard I have an UILabel and an UISwitch for the user to select if they want to remember the Member Id for login.

[image]

I have added a translation for the label text in Main.strings (Spanish) file:

```
/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Save Member ID"; ObjectID = "drT-iV-8Z7"; */
"drT-iV-8Z7.text" = "￼Guardar ID del miembro";
```

However, when I view in Spanish, the "Save Member ID" text is slightly indented.

[image]

I've confirmed that there is not any leading spaces, left justification is on and all of the labels have the same X coordinate.  I am not seeing this behavior with any of the other localized strings.

Has anyone experienced this issue before?  Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by deleting the Spanish phrase from my .strings file and then re-create the phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Such seemingly inexplicable UI glitches can be caused by:

- *Categories* of `UILabel` that your code might contain;
- Property changes using the `appearance` protocol

Check for the occurrence of these in your project.

The screenshot seems to indicate that you are modifying the labels with borders, rounded corners, etc. Examine your code doing these modifications. Specifically, you want to check if `leftView` and/or `leftViewMode` have been altered in any way.

Another thing to check is a project-wide text search for this phrase. It could be substituted again with the typo.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  There is no code it is all handled in Storyboard. I've compare the properties for both labels and they are the same.  The text only exists in the .strings file for the storyboard.

FYI, the borders and rounded corners are on an underlying UIButton.

Comment: What about the other scenarios I mentioned? Are the labels aligned to something that could change?

Comment: Thanks again for the response.  All great suggestions. I was able to resolve the issue. Apparently when I cut and pasted the Spanish phrase from the spec document into my .strings file there must of been some sort of weird encoding in that text. I deleted the phrase and typed it in manually and it is now displaying correctly.

Comment: Well, I was close with the search. An up-vote would be nice.